# Should I ask for client’s budget before the initial first meeting?

Tags: client-relations, freelance, design-process

First of all, is it a good idea to ask a potential client for a ballpark budget they are thinking to work with? I just don’t want to meet with somebody who has a very low budget, and who could be surprised during our first meeting that I’m not the cheapest guy in town.

So what do you think my first step should be when a client sends me an e-mail, wanting to discuss a project? The client has no idea what I charge, beside the fact that the client likes the work I do.

Answer (score 9):

Related: [Whose responsibility is to give budget for job: Freelancer or Client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/whose-responsibility-is-to-give-budget-for-job-freelancer-or-client/1317#1317) from freelance.stackexchange.com

**I never ask for budget**. I have my pricing. I price what is inline with my pricing. *Then* the client can mention their budget if they want to.

To me "What's your budget" has only a few outcomes:

1. The Client lies about budget in order to get you to price lower than you traditionally would. Assuming there may be overages or using the extra margin for negotiating.
2. Gives unethical workers the opportunity to price *more* than they would if they were unaware of the budget.

Neither of these should be a contributing factor to your pricing. Therefore, there's little need to know the client's budget before providing a quote/bid. You should know your rates, gather an understanding of what the client needs, then price based on your rates. Only afterwards may budget be a concern if the client indicates their budget is lower than your pricing. They, obviously won't mention if their budget is higher.

I **never** buy **anything** starting the purchase by exposing what I have allotted spend. That almost always results in unnecessarily inflated pricing. Many, many clients in my experience feel just this way.

Asking for budget is really only valid if you are purchasing prefabricated items which range in pricing. Service industries in general rarely deal in prefabricated items other than perhaps "parts".

Note that while I do not directly ask for a "budget" I do ask *pointed* questions to determine the general spending range a client is considering. I do not want to put a great deal of time and effort into working up a quote only to find out the client wanted a project done for $50.

So, during conversations I will make comments such as "I'll have to do more research, but generally projects such as this run $xxxxx to $xxxxx. Is that okay?" Or "This is going to run a few thousand dollars." then merely gauge the response.

I get a **ton** of work *because* I do not "ask for budget". I price my time and the work involved, not based upon what the client has to spend. Could I make additional money by asking for a budget then targeting that figure with my quotes? Probably. Is it worth the headache to me? No. I use value-based pricing and I feel my prices position me in the market where I wish to be. Any attempt to "chase budgets" just means I may not be confident in my pricing or I want to take advantage of clients willing to spend more than I would traditionally charge.

There are **no** undetermined costs in design in my opinion. None. It's not like remodeling a kitchen where you must know a budget to purchase materials. There's no such factor in design. *All* designers know costs before ever discussing a project. The only variable is the time needed and third party licenses. All of which can be determined by discussing the scope of any project with any client.

In short, for design work, the only variable is my time and effort. Not material costs. Without material costs, I see no relevant reason to ever ask for a budget. *Service* industries are generally not budget-oriented on the whole. It's a myth that design (a service) should be. It's only *product* industries that need to be aware of a budget in order to determine materials which need to be purchased. There are no "materials" in design projects 99% of the time. And any standard materials should be built into pricing as overhead, not per client budget.

---

> Based on the lengthy comments below. . . let me qualify a few things.....
>
> - I don't gain clients via cold calling.
> - I don't gain clients via Craigslist ads or similar.
> - 99.9% of my clients come to me via word of mouth and are therefore already "pre-qualified" as reputable clients. I don't really deal with many "looky-loo" clients or uneducated clients that need to be convinced design is a necessary business expense.
> - I don't assume my clients have little or no money, in fact just the opposite. My assumption is that anyone contacting me is prepared to pay my rates. I'm always open to the pricing conversation, but I don't start from the inferior mindset of "errr.. can you possibly pay me this much?"
> - I never apologize for my rates. They have been established and proven over several years as valid rates for my particular market.
> - I'm just as comfortable passing on a client unwilling to pay my rates as I am  taking on a client who *will* pay my rates.
> - I've been doing this for quite some time. I'm not just starting out or trying to establish a client base. I have extensive experience in what I do so clients looking to "just throw something together cheap" are not the type of clients I am approached by. Don't get me wrong, I do the quick cheap stuff all the time, but for already established clients. Not new clients.
> - I have minimum prices. I share this during early conversations. Client: *"How much to create XXXXX."* Me: *"My minimum for any XXXX project is $xxx but I can't really provide solid pricing without fully understanding what you need."* Or me: *"XXX projects range from $XXX to $XXXXX depending upon what's desired."*
>
> All these factors lead to the answer (and subsequent comments) above.

---

Comment: Budget typically has a direct correlation with scope. A good designer helps the client with that and typically would need to understand the budget to fully help with defining scope.

Comment: This is also different than haggling over the price of a used car--but even then--if you are asking someone to help you with that process, they need to know if you're thinking $500 or $5000 as that drastically changes the solution that will fit your needs.

Comment: I disagree @DA01. I can price my time based on an understanding of the project. **Then** budget can be addressed if the client can't meet my pricing. But knowing the client's budget is does not alter my pricing. It only alters what I may or may not be able to complete. And as I edited, where items, such as a used car, is concerned, budget is a factor, but in services it shouldn't be at the start.

Comment: @Scott I disagree , I can do a $500 and a $5000 logo, it all depends on the project scope and what the client is looking for. Also different business entities will have different nuances, those nuances can eat up a lot of time. Before meeting with someone its a good idea to see if its going to be even worth your time.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong. But it's not an opinion that I share. Design is about a lot of things, including meeting the business objectives. All business objectives should have defined ideas of budgets. If a client hasn't thought about budget, I'm not sure they're prepared to think about the project.

Comment: And that's where I explore.. the project. By exploring I know the scope of work. I know the nuances. I know the breadth of initial use, the intended future use, the desire for repurposing, etc. All of which I can price much better than simply knowing "We want to spend $xxx on this."

Comment: Final point: budget goes well beyond your time as well. In a lot of cases, they're hiring you to manage a project beyond just your hourly tasks. There's printing, web hosting, research, user testing, vendors, etc, etc. You have to know the budget to bring that all together and still fulfill the clients needs.

Comment: Again.. if you know the requirements you price based upon your pricing. **Not** on what the client has to spend. If I'm hiring you and you ask me "What's your budget" I'll either A) Lie or B) find someone else.

Comment: @scott...ah! I see what you are getting at. Asking for budget should never be about what you are going to charge or how you are going to price. It's about exactly what you are talking about...'exploring the project'. I agree completely that the budget question isn't about you changing your price. Rather, it's just as you say...it's about getting an understanding of the project.

Comment: @scott, how much time/money do you lose exploring in that manner? Sometimes its good to know upfront if the project is going to fall in your ballpark.

Comment: None @CtrlAltDesign and I build repeat business like gangbusters.

Comment: @scott, say you are hiring an architect to design a house and they ask you your budget. Would you seriously lie or walk away? How can they possibly know what the scope of the project is without you having an idea of what you're going to spend on it?

Comment: @Da01 I explain what I want. Get a ballpark then adjust my wants. I NEVER tell ANYONE I have $xxx to spend. 99.5% of the time they'll  price VERY close to what I have to spend, not what the job REALLY costs.

Comment: @Scott, what i meant was, exploring for projects that don't come to fruition is lost money.

Comment: I guess you are a very paranoid consumer. :) In general though, if the client is not even sure what things cost, then they're not prepared to really tackle the project. And that can be a huge waste of time for people like the OP. A business should have an idea of what they want to spend to achieve X and from there they should hire the people that will help them achieve that--not trying to find the lowest bidder.

Comment: Again, none @CtrlAltDesign if  my pricing is within their budget I get the work. If my pricing is above their budget, we discuss options to lower pricing. If none can be found, I pass on the work. If anything there may be a slight loss-leader to it, but nothing which has ever been detrimental enough to warrant concern.

Comment: I realize this may not be the "norm" but it has been **exceptionally** beneficial to all my client relations. There is *never* a question of whether I'm overcharging or not.

Comment: That may be very well for you, which is great. But it really depends on the project. Lots of projects requires hours upon hours upon hours of research to come up with even ballpark estimates. Think of a large promotional campaign where you may be doing design, ad buys, trade shows, large print runs, etc. If the client isn't realistic walking in the door with budgets, a lot of time can be eaten up getting to that point.

Comment: I know it's fairly common in the industry to ask for a budget. But being on both the purchasing and delivering end, I've seen how unfavorable the "What's your budget" question is received. Sorry, you may think it' a perfectly valid question, but you aren't seeing how the client cringe and look at each other sideways when you ask.

Comment: @Scott Why would the client cringe?

Comment: I've never seen a client cringe when I ask about budget. It's usually expected.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree. And you all can keep +1'ing each other's comment s:) I honestly feel it's a *horrible* and unnecessary question until *after* you've provided pricing.

Comment: I just don't understand, are you pricing by hour or by project? how can you give an accurate estimate with the way design projects can vary?

Comment: Like I said, it's not a wrong opinion. And I'm glad it works for you. But it's fairly atypical in this industry for plenty of legitimate reasons that actually benefit both parties.

Comment: Sorry, I have yet to see or hear a *legitimate* reason to know how much money the client has in their pocket.

Comment: @scott we're not asking what a client has in their pocket. We're asking them what their budget is for this project. It seems that you are coming at it from an unusual angle where all projects are static and all that changes is what you'll charge based on the budget. I'm saying just the opposite. Projects vary wildly and the budget has nothing to do with the rate you charge. It has everything to do with what the project scope is and will be. They are hiring you to consult. Budgeting is part of that.

Comment: Perhaps a bad analogy...but back to car shopping. $5000 vs. $50000. If a customer has 50k to spend, most places won't get away selling a $5000 car to them with inflated markups. Instead, they'll sell them a $50,000 car. There isn't a static price for cars. You have to know the budget to know what will fit their needs and wants.

Comment: That's prefab items DA01... not *services*. Bad, and completely unrelated, analogy. Here's a better one... you want to remodel your kitchen... would you want to tell the contractor you're willing to spend $40,000 or would you rather explain what you want done, then see the pricing for it?

Comment: @scott...ah, good analogy. I would be prepared and have a ballpark budget in mind based on what I want. If I were the contractor, I can do a 10k kitchen, or I could do a 100k kitchen. But I need to know what the customer wants to spend on it to even start drawing up what they want. Budgets are a key part of all contracting/construction projects.

Comment: But maybe you are thinking of this as more as an RFP process? Admittedly, that is a bit different. That's where clients are bidding out jobs. In that case, they are wanting exactly what you are suggesting...you'll give them a price based on their project request. (This is also why plenty of places just pass on RFPs...they are often a waste of time)

Comment: See I have some "base" pricing or minimums which I share because it's not worth taking on a project if it's below my minimum for that type of project. But I share my minimums, I don't ask for budget. So for a kitchen remodel, I'd state' "My minimum fee for a kitchen remodel is $15,000" then if the client is still interested I invest the time to explore what they want.

Comment: I think it would be good to have these opposing points in an answer.

Comment: Ah, but a kitchen remodel isn't about the contractors fee. It's about the contractors fee + vendors + appliances + cabinets, etc, etc. All that has to be factored into the solution. And one would need a budget to get to that point.

Comment: (Good conversation, btw!)

Comment: Yes... and that's where I explore. If they meet my minimum, it's worth my time to tell then "A GE range will add an additional $2k to the budget where a Kenmore will only add $1k." Because I know that my fees are covered by the minimum, anything required above my time will increase the pricing. So it's then up the client just how far above the minimum they wish to go.

Comment: And I think that's why budget is important. If you spend the time to spec out a 100k kitchen based on their 'wants' only to find out they only have 16k to spend, you've just spend a chunk of time that you're not going to get paid for. Whereas if they said they had a 16k budget from the start, you'd be able to better meet their needs with a different solution from the get-go.

Comment: I can see that point, I just have never found a situation where that works for me. If I spec out that $100k kitchen, I have a model to show all future clients to gage where they are at... and thus, it's NOT wasted time and I still don't need to ask for budget :)

Comment: When it comes to remodeling business, clients are usually well versed in the type of money they need to spend before asking for quotes. When a remodeler comes in and gives a quote, clients are not surprised about the quotes they receive.  In most graphic design cases, clients are clueless, often times they come from an angle, that design should be free, or they can hire somebody who needs a practice.  Thats what clientsfromhell.com is all about.

Comment: 34 comments, I think this is a record! As you know, comments are temporary, but there's a lot of interesting points here that would deserve some prominent space. Why not turn some of these into new questions?

Comment: @Dominic It's not really an issue of scale. In fact, the bigger the client, the more likely there's already a budget well established and expectations are equal on both sides as the information is shared.

Comment: FYI, your last bullet is essentially talking about budget. Perhaps not directly, but it's there to come to the same end results. :)

Comment: Also: Let me apologize. I completely didn't see the "before initial meeting" caveat in the OP's title. I'd argue my point in a MUCH LESS vehement way in that light. One shouldn't ask for budget before even meeting with the client. That should come up in initial scope defining/planning meetings.

Comment: @DA01 regarding that last bullet. I can see that perception. the very **important difference** (although perhaps subtle) is that I am *not* asking the client what they are willing to spend. I am setting boundaries for what I'm willing work on.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, It is totally legitimate. It's usually the second question I ask after whats the project about.

"What kind of budget are we dealing with?"

This can give you a general idea if it falls in your realm and worth your      time. Generally over email or phone.

I usually prefer phone a call, you can hear about the project, budget and get a feel for the client and if you want to move forward. Meeting IRL takes time. If the project doesn't bring in money, its wasted time for your business.

Comment: I usually ask this question - "What kind of budget are we looking at?". Whenever I do this, I end up facing another question, ''What do you think will it cost?". The problem is, maybe I estimate too low according to what client was expecting or just the opposite. In later case, they don't even want to negotiate. Errrr !!!

Comment: You can help the client focus by asking what their main strategic goals are for the project. This allows you to qualify the budget question by noting that there are many ways to achieve their goals but each has trade-offs. Knowing the working budget allows you to pinpoint those trade offs that are most suitable - or suggest that the project can’t be achieved within those constraints.

Answer (score 5):

[updated clarification: *Before* meeting with the client? Likely, no. That is just the wrong time to ask. But *as early as possible* in the discovery/scope defining process? Absolutely.]

The job of a designer (or anyone providing a business service, for that matter) is to provide a solution that meets the business objectives of the client.

If your solution costs more than the budget. You've failed.

If your solution falls far short of the scope that was intended. You've failed.

That's not to say client budgets and your costs are fixed. Rather, you have to know what the budget is so that both sides can adjust as needed/capable. And that can go in both directions. If you're a designer that typically makes WordPress sites and find out that the client has a half million dollar budget, obviously they aren't likely looking for a WordPress solution and have a much larger scope in mind. Maybe that's something you can accommodate, or maybe it's something you need to pass on.

And conversely, maybe the client wants a logo for $500 and you normally charge at least $2000. Knowing the budget up front lets you make a decision as to whether you need to pass (just not worth your time) or adjust the solutions you provide to meet that budget (maybe it's a really fun project that is worth you finding a solution for).

In other words, the only way to properly deliver a solution tailored to the client's objectives and goals is to understand the scope of the project and a key part of that is understanding the expected budget. Knowing that up front hopefully allows you and/or the client to adjust expectations and scope as needed from the get-go. Worse case, it at least will make it clear if you and the potential client are just not a match. Both you and the client will benefit from knowing that sooner than later.

It's business. Everyone knows that money will be exchanged. The sooner that's figured out, the less time will be wasted by all parties and the quicker solutions can be started on.

UPDATE:

My original answer didn't address the 'prior to meeting with them' part of the question. That's a bit different of a question than what I initially answered. In that situation, I'd say "probably not" as there's going to be a lot more that has to be thought about than just the budget. That usually has to happen in a more in-depth meeting where budget--along with scope, goals, objectives, strategy, business needs, etc will all be talked about and will work together to determine possible solutions to fit budgets.

Comment: You can phrase the question as "To avoid misaligned expectations, I would like to know what the budget is" to emphasize what this answer focuses on.

Comment: "If your solution costs more than the budget," then there may be a mismatch between solution and client. Just because the client has a budget of $50 for a logo doesn't mean I can provide a logo for $50. (or, I *can*, but it won't be anywhere as good as the $500 logo.) So either the client has to adjust budget, or the solution has to be different. Neither of those is "failure."

Comment: Those opening two sentences are so flawed. Not every solution provider will be able to (or desire to) provide solutions to every budget.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum you misunderstood (or I mistated). I agree with you. What you are saying is the same as what I'm saying. It's a failure *if* those adjustments aren't made. And one can't make those adjustments without knowing what the budget is.

Comment: @Paul how is it flawed? If you can't provide the solution with stated budget, then you pass on the job. You of course, have to know what the budget is to make that decision. I'm not saying you must take every job. I'm saying that the jobs a designer does take, meeting the budget is part of measuring success.

Comment: @DA01 I don't think you're making it clear in your answer that the cost of your solution and the budget are both adjustable. You're presenting it as "Here's the cost. There's the budget. If they don't match, it's game over." If there's room to address either side, you should edit your answer to reflect that. If the two sides can't compromise, then yes, you should pass on the job.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum good suggestion. I've added to the answer. Let me know if that helps clarify things.

Comment: @DA01 Yes, that's better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to qualify the client from the very beginning. Survey their products, marketing,  customer support, and competition to see if they're investing to an extent that will support your services. If not, a short phone conversation can determine if they plan to. Once you feel confident that they're in the ballpark, you can move ahead with an initial meeting.

Start with getting to know them better and sorting out what the expectations are in general and for the project at hand. Set a follow up meeting where you can review an itemized quote in person and discuss the scope of the process and deliverables they'll get out of the deal. At that point, you can discuss misalignment of the quote and budget. There's usually a little room on both ends to compromise. Most of it should center on adjusting the scope.

When you start with money, you're already breaking down the relationship. You want to be a business partner, not a vendor. Vendors are a commodity, but a good designer is creative capital. Start with relationship building, then the money will be a lot less painful for them.

Comment: But to contradict your last paragraph: vendors are usually shopped based on price (vendor X can do it for less). Business partners are shopped based on value. If money is a painful issue, then they would have just gone with bidding it out to vendors, rather than establishing a relationship with you as the designer.

Comment: I've coached more than a few start ups and small businesses through the rationale for finding a long-term partner over asking vendors to bid. It doesn't always take but when it does, you've found a great client.

Comment: I agree. And usually discourage designers from spending too much time on bidding. Responding to RFPs can be a frustrating and futile endeavor. You want to build a relationship...not fight your way to the lowest bid. :)

Comment: On the other hand, if you can get in as an approved vendor with a govt agency you might just find a cash cow :) Then you've got to suck it up and RFP your brains out.

Comment: Having both bid on .gov jobs as well as been a receiver of bids when working in .gov, I still say it can be a futile endeavor. So few RFPs provide sufficient detail as to what the scope of the solution they are looking for is. The other huge problem with RFPs is that there is often an attempt to define a solution in the RFP (which *is* needed to get accurate bids) but that usually means they didn't go through the proper process of finding the solution (which you usually want the designer to be a part of). I agree, it can be a cash cow if you get it. Just a pain to get it. :)

Comment: Agreed. I'm not patient enough but I know a lucky few who have been.

Answer (score 1):

I would never ever lead with a question about budget. Huge red flags.

It reminds me of when I interview for jobs and they "pre-screen" me with either fishing for prior salary information or what type of salary I'm expecting. If you were to go over to [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) you'd see the norm is to either avoid it, decline to answer, say you signed a confidentiality statement, or some other way to evade it including as Scott said --- lying.

> So What do you think my first step should be when a client writes me an email and says it wants to meet me about the project?

What you should do is learn everything about the client, presumably you should have already done some of this before even bidding or applying for the job unless they were referred to you by someone.

Then your first, and only step, is to schedule a time and place to meet with them.

Once they meet with you its your job to close them, to negotiate, and to come to terms everyone can agree with. If their budget is so vastly off from what your expectations are you can work with them as a consultant, refer them to a "newer" designer you know, or even piece meal it for them.

*Story:*

Last week I went to Lease a car. One of the dealerships I went to immediately sat me down with a form and started asking my first name, last name, budget, ranking my needs, all this stuff. I told him Ryan and that the rest is completely irrelevant at this point in time. He didn't get the sale.

I went to another dealership and after test driving a few cars the sales guy sat down with me and asked how much I had available to put down. I told him my bank account is none of his business. He didn't get the sale either.

I went to a third dealership and there were no forms or "fishing questions." The guy just discussed with me the rates they're allowed to do and what he was flexible on. I signed a 3 year lease.

*Moral of the story:* Price isn't determined by your client's budget so don't worry about it.

Comment: Your answer is fine, but is written in the context of *bidding* on a job. If we're talking RFP type relations, that makes sense. But hopefully one doesn't have to spend time bidding on every project. Hopefully a lot of their clients come to them based on reputation, past work, or the like. In those situations, it's expected that budgets will be talked about. In the end, *your price* isn't determined by the client's budget, but the *project costs* absolutely are.

Comment: Simple example...let's just take a basic project of printing a brochure. How can you bid the project properly without a ballpark budget? There's a vast difference between short-run photocopying and large-run 4 color offset printing with die-cuts and varnish. The design solution you come up with will vary quiet a bit knowing which way they want to go. You may charge exactly the same for both solutions, but knowing the budget is key to knowing which solution you should be working on providing them.

Comment: This varies a lot by culture. Where I live, if you turn down every job that 'fishes' your expected salary, you'll never get a job with a stranger. You'd be lucky if they don't demand your previous pay slip for these jobs! However, these budget questions are quite rude which will hurt your chances. Unless you're screening and filtering potential clients, it should be avoided.

Comment: @DA01 your last comment, about budget (in the other answer) before even meeting is the issue. Now that you said that everything else is fine. Your two comments here are perfectly acceptable but you have to meet with them and discuss things first.

Comment: @Ryan yep, that was a miss on my part. I agree, asking BEFORE the meeting is a different scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a budget selection option in the questionnaire I send out but not all clients fill that portion. I may have to make it mandatory. From my experience, writing proposals and then figuring out somehow that the prospect was no were near what I had proposed to be the cost can be discouraging. Another way to do it is to send an email with a rough estimate of the cost and ask if that fits their budget and then take it from there. But never lower your prices to get the job. Provide a design solution that fits their budget.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ask for client's budget before the initial first meeting?

I think the answer is **yes** because of several factors, most of them already mentioned in previous answers.

- **Time**: Your time and your client's time are valuable, knowing the allocated budget right away helps your customer avoid having to schedule a meeting with you for you to tell him you can't do his project because is underbudgeted. At the same time lets, you know right away if is going to be worth it for you to continue the conversation.
- **References**: Knowing the budget right away, if underbudgeted,  helps the client to get a reference from you of a colleague that might do the work for him.
- **Professionalism**: Both ways, let's you know if your client has invested time and effort in the planning of the project or if is just a whim.
- And overall, **avoiding frustrations** and helping you avoid getting clients that don't now what they want and are always trying to modify the project along the way.

For this reason, in our website we set up four our clients this [digital marketing project questionnaire](https://www.nuconet.com/new-project-questionnaire/). We usually send them to the page to fill it up but in occasions, we use it as a guide and fill it up ourselves with their info when in a phone, Skype or in-person meetings with our clients.

I hope this answer will be of use to you.

AC

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the budget question has to be asked at some point early on, to work you need to know how much you're paid. What's important is to know when & how to ask the question, and that will vary based on the industry & product/service type.

Ask about the budget when it makes sense, ask the clients about their goal and reason for their inquiry. THis will help you set a price range & better understand the client.

Ask questions, set a template & reasonable time for providing quotes.

Examples: [c]  = client

- Selling A Car:

  - [c] Hi, Im looking to buy a car:
  - Do you already have a car?
  - [c] Yes
  - Why are you looking to buy a car ?

    - [c] Answer 1: My old car broke down & I just need something to get me to & from work
    - [c] Answer 2: I started a new well paying job 6 months ago & thought I should upgrade to a better & more comfortable car.
- Selling a website:

  - [c] Hi,I need a website, how much does it cost?
  - I custom build websited to fit my clients' business needs, I would like to ask few questions to help me better understand your needs:

    - What industry are you in ?
    - What’s the purpose of the website ? Is it to provide information about your business, products & services; showcase your work; gather information through web forms; sell online (ecommerce) and/or other reasons ?
    - Provide at least 2 example websites from your industry that you like, to get an idea of what you’re expecting in terms of design & functionality.
    - Then later on in the 2nd or 3rd email ask : What’s your budget for this project ? ( [1] $800-$1000, [2] $1000-$2000, [3] up to $5,000, [4] up to $10,000)
  - Possible client answers:

    - Answer 1: I run a fish & chips, I want to provide information, contact form & allow customers to order online. I've seen website prices at $200 on freelancer.com , can you do it cheaper ?
    - Answer 2: I run a restaurant, my goal is to provide unique experience, quality food & memorable service. I'm looking for someone to make sure customer can easily find me & order online. I don't have a budget in mind yet but I'm looking for a unique website. I've recently spent alot of money renovating the shop & i've attached some photos of the shop so you know what I mean.

In these examples, you can determine a price range based on what they say & your experience in the field.

(if anyone got examples / scenarios for huge multi million $ projects, please comment below or post an answer)